# "dup" function, "more" and redirection

Tags: c, unix, stdin, dup

I have a problem with this little code for educational purposes. I can not understand how it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define FNAME "info.txt"
#define STDIN 0
int main(){

   int fd;
   fd = open(FNAME, O_RDONLY);

   close(STDIN); //entry 0 on FDT is now free
   dup(fd); //fd duplicate is now stored at entry 0 
   execlp("more","more",0); 
}
```

By starting this program it prints the contents of the file "info.txt" on terminal. I can not understand why! Where is the link between "more" and STDIN (keyboard or file)?

Why if i use more with no args and without redirection on file it just shows a help screen but whit redirection it uses the file as input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dup` always gives you the lowest available file descriptor number.

By default all process will have `0`, `1` and `2` for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. You are opening a file from that you will get a file descriptor value `3`. After that you have closed `stdin`. Now calling `dup` after that will give you a lowest available value as a duplicate file descriptor for `3`, so you will be getting `stdin` as duplicate file descriptor for `3`.

```
int main()
{
   int fd, fd2;
   fd = open(FNAME, O_RDONLY); //This will be 3

   fd2 = dup(fd); //This will be 4 because 4 is the lowest available value
   close(STDIN); //entry 0 on FDT is now free
   dup(fd); //fd duplicate is now stored at entry 0 
   execlp("more","more",0); 
}
```

And here why its displaying the content of the file is, `more` command can be used in two ways.

- more filename
- command | more

In your exec, you are not giving any `filename` as command line argument for `more` command. So its executing in `pipe` mode, by reading it from stdin.

Comment: I know that. I can not understand why `more` uses the STDIN as input instead of show only the help screen

Comment: It checks whether the input is a terminal, and shows help screen if it is. Otherwise it reads stdin, to allow `some commands | more` usage which is fairly common.

Comment: The "more" command checks if the input is a terminal, and if so says "Sorry, you haven't given me any input". If it's not a terminal [such as in this case, a file], then it goes on and prints the content.

Comment: Ok.I t's the same of `more info.txt | more` Thanks raja!